# Unsure why jQuery .prev() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is, when I hover over a link, make its right border change colour as well as make the previous link's border change colour.

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gigs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
$("li a").hover(function() {
     $(this).animate({
         color: '#0099FF',
         borderRightColor: '#0099FF'
     }, 500);

     $(this).prev().animate({borerRightColor: '#0099FF'}, 500); 

}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        borderRightColor: '#FFFFFF'
    }, 500);

    $(this).prev().animate({borerRightColor: '#FFFFFF'}, 500);      
});
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're looking for: `$(this).parent().prev().children('a:first')`

Answer (score 6):

The selector `li a` selects each `<a>` element. `.prev()` selects the previous sibling, not the "previous element in the collection," and there is no previous element for the `<a>`s because they have no siblings, only parents. Try this instead:

```
$(this).closest('li').prev().children().animate(...);
```

Also, you've used `borerRightColor` instead of `borderRightColor`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for `.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

> **Description:** Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

The links are not siblings.

```
$("li").hover(function() { 
        $(this).children().animate({
                    color: '#0099FF',
                    borderRightColor: '#0099FF'
                        }, 500);
        $(this).prev().children().animate({borerRightColor: '#0099FF'}, 500);    
}, function () {    
        $(this).children().animate({
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    borderRightColor: '#FFFFFF'
                        }, 500);
        $(this).prev().children().animate({borerRightColor: '#FFFFFF'}, 500);    
});
```

[Here's a demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WSHT/8/). I put the hover on the `<li>` while I was at it so you aren't traversing all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` context refers to the `<a>` element being hovered, not the `<li>`. The `<a>` element doesn't have a previous sibling.

Use the `parent` method to access the `<li>`:

```
$(this).parent()......
```